# How Browser download files (via HTTP or FTP)

Tags: http, web, browser, ftp

Please forgive me if it seems a silly question, I have this doubt and couldn't find the answer on the web.

How browser and any other downloader downloads a file, which protocol is working at the backend `HTTP` or `FTP`.

As we all know `HTTP` can be used to transfer text, which can be rendered by the browser. It can also send binary data.

Let's say I want to access a webpage at `www.xyz.com/index.aspx` which has a static webpage with 2 images. As we all know a total of 3 HTTP requests will be made, one for webpage and other 2 for images.

But what about other files which have a big size. I mean suppose I'm downloading an mp3/mp4 files (having link given on the webpage). So, what protocol is working at the backend HTTP or FTP.

Comment: It's whatever the URL says.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the url :

```
ftp://www.example.com/bla/bla/bla01.zip
```

will be fetched via ftp, and

```
http://www.example.com/bla/bla/bla01.zip
```

will be fetched via http

Of course we cannot simply change http:// with ftp:// as http need an http server, and ftp need an ftp server.

Comment: how much data can be enclosed in 1 HTTP Response packet.

Comment: @Atinesh you can send any size of data

Comment: but if that is so, until now all the websites I am using and downloading content from, nowhere I have seen them using ftp, does that mean all of them are using HTTP to transfer files?

Comment: Yes, nowadays most servers using HTTP to download or upload files, even for big files